# How does one center the images in rows of three?

Tags: html, css

Alright, so I'm back with another question about centering my images. None of the advice I received (older post) solved the issue. Grant it, the images are no longer scattered and take up a different amount of space. They are lined on top of each other on the left side of the screen. I have ten images. I'm trying to achieve two rows of three centered images with the extra photo either right above or below the two rows. I took out any break elements because they didn't seem to be doing anything.

```css
  div.gallery {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    width: 500px;
 font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Monaco", "Courier New", "monospace";
 color: yellow;
  
    }

    div.gallery:hover {
    border: 5px solid yellow;
    }

    div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }

    div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<h1 class="work1"><center><a class="ex1">Photography Assignment</a></center></h1>
 
 

 
 <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="images/SS1.png">
  <img src="images/SS1.png" alt="Margaret's bag" height="200" width="300">
  </a>
   <div class="desc">An extreme close up of Margaret's bag</div>
 </div> 
 
 
 
 <div class="gallery">
   <a target="_blank" href="images/SS2.png">
  <img src="images/SS2.png" alt="Margaret's notes" height="200" width="300">
 </a>
   <div class="desc">A picture of Margaret's bag</div>
 </div>  
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="images/SS3.png">
 <img src="images/SS3.png" alt="Close up of Margaret's face" height="200" width="300">
 </a>
   <div class="desc">A close up of Margaret against a pink house</div>
 </div>  
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="images/SS4.png">
 <img src="images/SS4.png" alt="A medium shot of Margaret" height="200" width="300">
 </a>
   <div class="desc">A medium shot of Margaret</div>
 </div> 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="images/SS5.png">
 <img src="images/SS5.png" alt="A medium long shot of Margaret" height="200" width="300">
 </a>
   <div class="desc">A medium long shot of Margaret</div>
 </div> 
 
 
 
 
 
 <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="images/SS6.png">
 <img src="images/SS6.png" alt="A long shot of Margaret in motion" height="200" width="300">
 </a>
   <div class="desc">A long shot of Margaret in motion</div>
 </div> 
 
 
 
 
 <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="images/SS7.png">
 <img src="images/SS7.png" alt="A upward medium shot of Margaret" height="200" width="300">
 </a>
   <div class="desc">An upward medium shot of Margaret</div>
 </div> 
 
 
 
 
 <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="images/SS8.png">
 <img src="images/SS8.png" alt="A telephoto shot of a sunflower with Margaret in the background" height="200" width="300">
 </a>
   <div class="desc">A telephoto shot of a sunflower with Margaret in the background</div>
 </div> 
 
 
 
 
 
 <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="images/SS9.png">
 <img src="images/SS9.png" alt="A telephoto shot of Margaret" height="200" width="300">
 </a>
   <div class="desc">A telephoto shot of Margaret</div>
 </div> 
 
 
 
 
 <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="images/SS10.png">
 <img src="images/SS10.png" alt="A wide shot of Margaret getting into a firetruck" height="200" width="300">
 </a>
   <div class="desc">A wide shot of Margaret</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `div.gallery { ... ; display: inline-block; }`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired layout using Flexbox with these updates:

1. Add a container div to wrap around all 10 of the gallery divs.
2. Add this CSS for the new container div:

   ```
   .container {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: space-evenly;
     align-items: flex-start;
   }
   ```
3. Add to the CSS `width:30%;` to the `div.gallery`

Here are these edits in CodePen:
https://codepen.io/jessbodie/pen/OONpRE?editors=1100

Refer to great article: "[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)"

Comment: @Jack Did this or another solution work for the original question?